# Minikube start stuck while Creating docker container Windows 10

Tags: windows, minikube

Trying to start minikube locally. Using Win 10 + docker + minikube.

```
minikube start
* docker "minikube" container is missing, will recreate.
* Creating docker container (CPUs=2, Memory=7909MB) ...
! StartHost failed, but will try again: recreate: creating host: create host timed out in 360.000000 seconds
* docker "minikube" container is missing, will recreate.
* Creating docker container (CPUs=2, Memory=7909MB) ...\
```

I also tried to use virtualbox `--driver=virtualbox` and Hyper-v `minikube start --driver=hyperv --force` but got the same - always stuck on creating container.

```
* Creating hyperv VM (CPUs=2, Memory=6000MB, Disk=20000MB) ...| E0307 13:19:57.585863   14560 main.go:137] libmachine: [stderr =====>] : Hyper-V\Get-VM : Hyper-V was unable to find a virtual machine with name "minikube".
At line:1 char:3
+ ( Hyper-V\Get-VM minikube ).state
+   ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : InvalidArgument: (minikube:String) [Get-VM], VirtualizationException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : InvalidParameter,Microsoft.HyperV.PowerShell.Commands.GetVM



! StartHost failed, but will try again: creating host: create host timed out in 360.000000 seconds
E0307 13:20:03.010792   14560 main.go:137] libmachine: [stderr =====>] : Hyper-V\Get-VM : Hyper-V was unable to find a virtual machine with name "minikube".
At line:1 char:3
+ ( Hyper-V\Get-VM minikube ).state
+   ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : InvalidArgument: (minikube:String) [Get-VM], VirtualizationException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : InvalidParameter,Microsoft.HyperV.PowerShell.Commands.GetVM
```

SVM is enabled in bios.

Any idea how to solve it? Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0):

We had the same issue and for us it turned out that WSL is currently unable to successfully connect to the kubernetes container managed by Docker Desktop. This is caused by a port forwarding issue in recently-released WSL 1.1.3: see https://github.com/microsoft/WSL/issues/9751